# SQL - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SUM(Cost) "Total Cost"'

Tags: sql, ms-access, phpmyadmin

I can't figure this out. I have used the command below in phpmyadmin with no problems but I create my database in Microsoft Access and suddenly the query has a syntax error. I've checked it over and over and I get the same answer everytime. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT vet_id, Visit_date, SUM(Cost) "Total Cost" FROM medication
GROUP BY vet_id, Visit_date;
```

Comment: don't compare mysql and access. access has a ton of syntax warts and downright oddities/stupidities about it, like any other db.

Comment: And if you're not using `phpmyadmin` anymore, it's probably best not to tag it, only what is relevant to your current situation.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Will put them to good use in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT vet_id, Visit_date, SUM(Cost) AS [Total Cost]
FROM medication
GROUP BY vet_id, Visit_date;
```

Access requires you to include the `AS` keyword when you alias a field expression.

I enclosed the alias in square brackets.  If you use quotes instead ... `AS "Total Cost"` ... Access will include those quotes in the column header.

Comment: Works great, Thanks, :)

Comment: Good point about the quotes. Is `as` an ANSI requirement? I note that MS T-SQL doesn't require it - not that it bears many other similarities to Access SQL anyway.

Comment: @underscore_d I don't think so, but not certain about that.  And Access is not consistent about `AS` for aliases.  It is required when you alias a field expression, but not required when you alias a `FROM` data source.  So Access would accept either of these: `FROM medication AS m` or `FROM medication m`

Comment: Ha, that's an interesting piece of trivia, thanks! Access SQL just gets weirder ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When using aliases, you generally need to include the `AS` keyword to indicate which column or aggregate you want to use an an alias :

```
  SELECT vet_id, 
         Visit_date, 
         SUM(Cost) AS [Total Cost] 
    FROM medication
GROUP BY vet_id, Visit_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. Very helpful :)